# Angular 4 FormControl autocomplete initial data

Tags: angular, typescript

i am using material.angular.io components for my app - specifically autocomplete. I am adapting it to use as **multi-select**, and now I have an issue with loading initial values:

code:

```
export class CaseActivityTimeEditComponent implements OnInit {
    public clients: Client[];
    clientControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

    getClients(): void {
        this.clientService.getClients(null,null)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.clients = data;
            });
    }

    constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getClients();

        this.filteredClients = this.clientControl.valueChanges
            .startWith(this.clients) ==> this.clients is UNDEFINED
            .map(val => val ? this.filterClient(val) : this.clients);

    }
}
```

Basically, I'd like to populate initial values for this **FormControl**, but `this.getClients()` takes **some time** to get initial values.

What is the best practice to make this work?

Comment: Put `this.filteredClients` inside `.subscribe` only and You can put loader until you get data. If it looks ok for you. Or if you don't want to display template at all, then try to use `resolve` in route itself.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
getClients(): void {
    this.clientService.getClients(null,null)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.clients = data;
            // realize your auto complete function here because 
            // 'this.clients' is now defined
        });
}
```